# Почему выводит ошибку 500 HTTP

Tags: php

Написал скрипт на `php` для открытие файла 
но когда заливаю на локальный сервер, браузер пишет страница не доступна `HTTP 500`, когда убираю php скрипт, страница открывается и `html` разметка выводится

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>xss</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="xss2.php" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="FILE"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $F = $_POST['FILE'];
            if($file=fopen($F, "r")){
                print("ok!");
            else{
                die("Erorr");
            }   
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я как минимум вижу тут ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: А вам следует включить показ ошибок и использовать современное IDE с подсветкой синтаксиса, а не Блокнот.

Comment: а че `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` и `error_reporting(-1);` уже вышли из моды, да?

Comment: Ну или логи глянуть на веб-сервере. Это вообще первое,что обычно делают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фигурная скобка должна быть перед else проблема в этом, у вас фигурные скобки не правильно расположены. Поэтому и выдаёт 500 ошибку, когда видите такую ошибку в первую очередь проверяйте синтаксис.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $F = $_POST['FILE'];
            if($file=fopen($F, "r")){
                print("ok!");
           } else { // в этой строчке скобка перед else
                die("Erorr");
            }   
          // } - отсюда надо убрать
        }
```

Ну и файл вам не открыть так, форма должна иметь атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"` и файл надо получить из массива `$_FILES`